# Using Listbox Change Event to Select Option Buttons

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, radio-button, powerpoint

[image]

I would like to update the option buttons at the top when the user selects any item in listbox2. The D1-4 part is the difficulty, so if the the item begins with D2, the program would select Optionbutton 2.

Listbox2 is populated by a dynamic array of the form [Question Title][Difficulty 1 to 4]. When the user clicks option button 1, for example, it updates the array (Arr) and updates listbox2. This works as intended until I activate the listbox 2 change event sub to make it do the above.

I done some investigating and noticed the ListBox2.ListIndex was returning the value -1 (not selected) even though an item was selected. But strangely this doesn't happen and works fine when disable the part of code which selects the relevant option buttons in the listbox2 change event.

I attach the code for the listbox2 change even and one of the option button click sub. (The other option buttons have virtually the same code, but for the other buttons).

Thank you in advance.

```
Private Sub ListBox2_Change() 'If listbox2 is selected/changed
If ListBox2.ListIndex = -1 Then 'Nothing in listbox2 is selected Then
Else
j = ListBox2.ListIndex 'track selected listbox2 index

If OptionButton1.Value = True Then

o = "1"
ElseIf OptionButton2.Value = True Then
o = "2"
ElseIf OptionButton3.Value = True Then
o = "3"
ElseIf OptionButton4.Value = True Then
o = "4"
End If

If Arr(ListBox2.ListIndex, 1) = o Then
ListBox2.Selected(j) = True
'MsgBox "values are same " & o & Arr(ListBox2.ListIndex, 1)
Else
    
'MsgBox "values are different " & o & Arr(ListBox2.ListIndex, 1)
'issue is here,

            Select Case Arr(ListBox2.ListIndex, 1)
            Case "1"
                OptionButton1.Value = True
                ListBox2.Selected(j) = True
                Exit Sub
            Case "2"
                OptionButton2.Value = True
                ListBox2.Selected(j) = True
                Exit Sub
            Case "3"
                OptionButton3.Value = True
                ListBox2.Selected(j) = True
                Exit Sub
            Case "4"
                OptionButton4.Value = True
                ListBox2.Selected(j) = True
                Exit Sub
            End Select

End If
End If
End Sub
```

Code for Option button 1 select.

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
MsgBox ListBox2.ListIndex
If ListBox2.ListIndex = -1 Then 'Nothing in listbox2 is selected Then

Else

    MsgBox ListBox2.ListIndex
    j = ListBox2.ListIndex 'track selected listbox2 index
    Arr(ListBox2.ListIndex, 1) = "1"
    
    ListBox2.Clear
    For i = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1) 'For Arr row index
    'MsgBox "(D" & Arr(i, 1) & ") " & Arr(i, 0)

    ListBox2.AddItem "(D" & Arr(i, 1) & ") " & Arr(i, 0)

    Next i
    ListBox2.Selected(j) = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming your **(D1)** stays the same (as in the number is always same position for each item in listbox) and your running a single select listbox you could do something in your listbox2 change event as simple as: `Me.Controls("OptionButton" & Mid(Me.ListBox2.Value,3,1)).Value = True`. That one line could replace all of the code you currently have for listbox2.

Comment: @Simon, thank you for your suggestion, I'm not using these as a form, so that code didn't work for me. Also the D1/2/3/4 values change based on what is stored in the array - listbox index row and second column. Thanks.

Comment: So try: `Me.OLEObjects("OptionButton" & Mid(Me.ListBox2.Value, 3, 1)).Object.Value = True`. Your D1/2/3 etc I'm meaning are they always there for every option? Is there always a **(Dx)** (x being number) in every line in listbox2 everytime? This would also only work as long as it doesn't go above 9 (because then it's 2 digits). Again it only works for single select listbox which you didn't mention whether it was or not.

Comment: Hi @Simon, yes it ranges from D1 to D4 and the number is always at the same place, and yes I'd like to select the relevant optionbutton1/2/3/4 in accordance. It is a single select listbox. I got an error with the code you suggested 'Compile Error: Method or data member not found'. Not sure if that is because I'm using PowerPoint and not Excel. Thank you again.

Comment: OK well it could be a Powerpoint thing. Why do you have Excel in the tags if it's not Excel? I haven't used PP in over 10 years so no idea. Will leave for someone else then.